# Finding Windows edition from filesystem

Tags: windows-7, windows-edition

I have switched laptops recently, and I decided I want to make the switch from Windows to Linux (and have gone with Ubuntu for now).

I have the "old" SSD from my previous machine, which has a Windows 7 installation on it. I'm trying to install Windows 7 on VMWare so I can run some of the programs that are only available on Windows (that Wine can't handle).

**I also have my Windows 7 key**, but I don't know which "edition" it is (Home vs. Premium vs. Ultimate, etc.)

The furthest I've gotten is looking at `explorer.exe`'s attributes to find this:

> Product Version: 6.1.7601.17567

But I couldn't find what that *means.*

I have the SSD mounted and am able to read/access the old filesystem. How can I find out what Windows edition I need to install on VMWare?

Comment: @techie007 Nope. I already know it's **Windows 7,** (see the question). The problem is figuring out the "edition," which none of the answers in the question you linked to talk about.

Comment: This answer: http://superuser.com/a/363068/23133 points to this SO post: [Determine Windows Version, Edition and Service Pack OF AN OFFLINE DISK IMAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709967/determine-windows-version-edition-and-service-pack-of-an-offline-disk-image)

Comment: The product version is the same regardless of the Windows 7 edition.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `regedit.exe` in Wine to `Load hive` of SOFTWARE registry. It's located at `Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE`, then look for value of `ProductName` and EditionID`under`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`

There is also open source offline registry editor for linux at http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/.

Comment: The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` hive is located at `X:\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE`. Also, the values you should look for are `ProductName` and `EditionID`.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `X:\Windows` folder on the SSD, and list all `.xml` files inside which are named after a Windows edition. If there's more than one, consider the [highest edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart) available.

Example:

```
X:\Windows\HomeBasic.xml
X:\Windows\HomePremium.xml
X:\Windows\Starter.xml
```

In this case the edition would be Home Premium.

Answer (score 0):

From the windows website: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/which-operating-system

**Click on the Start button**

**Right click on Computer**

**Select Properties**

**Look under Windows edition**

You should see "Windows 7 Enterprise" or "Windows 7 Home Premium" ...

Comment: He's not able to boot Windows.

Comment: He has his old SSD.  Plug in the SSD and pull the info.

Comment: You can't just plug in a drive from one laptop in another laptop and expect Windows to start up. Even if you get past any encryption, Windows is very likely to crash due to hardware differences.. Even if hardware is similar, it could still crash or go wonky - or may not even start up because of hardware fingerprint change.