# How to identify the Windows version of a dead install from Linux by having access only to its filesystem?

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I have a dead Windows install in one of my partitions. It doesn't have any boot data anymore. Practically, it is only a filesystem dump. But I have access to read any files on its filesystem.

How could I identify which Windows version is it? In the ideal case, I think there should be some configuration setting or any file unique to the different Windows versions. For example, on Debian-based Linux distros, I could simply read `/etc/debian_version`.

Unfortunately, I have access only to a Linux box to reach its hard disk. So, solutions requiring a Windows (for example, digging in the version of `ntoskrnl.exe`, or checking some registry settings) aren't in my case, feasible.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question didn't contain the answer I require. The solution I've found was that the `C:\Windows\System32\License.rtf` contains the windows version.

Comment: It is still a duplicate question.

Comment: @Moab My question is Linux-specific, while the other has only windows-specific answers.

Comment: I wish this question was de-duplicated, indeed the other question requires a working Windows installation, while this one is about Linux. I found that this answers the question: `strings ./Windows/System32/ntoskrnl.exe 2>/dev/null | grep amd64`. For me in printed `9600.18258.amd64fre.winblue_ltsb.160303-0600`, and googling for winblue indicates that this was the code name for Windows 8.1.

Comment: @DavidFaure Well, offer your answer in the thread your question is duplicate of. It will be useful.

Comment: It isn't clear why this is receiving reopen votes.  The solution that the OP states in the first comment here is the second-highest rated answer on the duplicate, and the duplicate is not Windows-specific.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes, the duplicate is Windows-specific, just as nearly all the answers of it, except the second most upvoted one. Which is essentially the same as the accepted answer of this question. But that answer were created a year after the here accepted answer - on this reason, that question could be closed as the dupe of this, and not vice versa.

Comment: Too bad this is marked as duplicate. To get the info from Linux, it can be done with `hivexget`. I added the details to that other question : https://superuser.com/a/1383325/53547

Comment: @mivk Thanks! It is a very useful answer. The closure of this question was a **BAD** decision, it is clearly visible for anybody... :-(

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame it was closed. Else I'd add this answer working for Ubuntu using chntpw: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71725634/1654116

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple. Look at the version of `<drive>:\Windows\System32\ntoskrnl.exe`

In the case of XP, look for `<drive>:\boot.ini`

If it is Vista+ you can look for the `<drive>:\Boot` folder.

For Windows 7+ you can look in device manager for the hidden `System Reserved` partition.

If there is a file named `license.rtf` in your `C:\Windows\System32` folder, it also contains your current Windows version.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is Win7+. The problem is that I don't have "System Reserved" partition any more. I have only the normal C:. How could I see the version of ntoskrnl.exe?

Comment: I finally solved by license.rtf, but your other solutions were also useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: @peterh for future reference, right-click, details. You will see info like (in my case: `NT OS & Kernel. Version: 6.1.7601`

Comment: For ref: `Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]` (when starting cmd.exe)

Comment: Err... ^- that is XP Pro "2002" SP 3 - 32bit, `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]` is Windows 8.1 Pro (64 bit)

Comment: Is there any way to tell a bit more detail, such as the difference between _Home Edition_ and _Professional Edition_, or whether it is _Windows 8_ or _Windows 8.1_?

Comment: @IQAndreas by using winver. Otherwise, it's almost impossible to tell

Comment: I didn't have luck with the above answers; what I ended up doing was looking at `bootmgr` on the boot partition. `strings -e l bootmgr -n20 | grep -i win` shows `10.0.17134.885 (WinBuild.160101.0800)`, and a quick google for the first bit shows this is a Win10 build #. Note that windows generally uses utf-16, so `strings` won't show much unless you tell it to look for little-endian 16-bit chars (`-e l`).

Answer (score 0):

You could also stream

`strings cmd.exe | find "Version"` might work too.  Most files have the version of windows in their property sheet, which is visible in the raw binary near the end of it.  One of these is the windows version.  It's in unicode though.

Comment: 1) `find "Version"` is a windows thing, I have linux and use grep. 2) It gave only a cryptic xml data, the only version info was some like "5.1.0.0" which can be anything between winxp and win7. But your answer may be useful for the googlers of the future, so here is a +1.

Comment: You could load it in some sort of text editor or viewer, and look there,

`grep -i "Version"` will do the same thing as windows 'find'.

Comment: `find /i "search-data"` == `grep -i "search-data"`.

Comment: Cmd has no built-in version numbers that I could find. `strings ntoskrnl.exe | grep 5.1` did the trick instead (of course every Windows version has its own [major.minor build](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version) to search for)