# Get windows version information from hard drive

Tags: windows

I have a computer hard drive that I need to replace. The owner of the computer doesn't remember which windows version she had. I connected her hard drive to my computer and I can see all her system files, but I cannot find any information on system (windows 7,8 or 10). Her operating system does't work so I cant use `MSINFO32` and there is no sticker with that information on her computer. Is there a way to find this information?

Comment: All Windows OEM devices are required to have a COA sticker on the device.  This will indicate which version of Windows was installed on the device.  You can determine which version of Office based on the contents of Microsoft Office within the Program Files (or Program Files x86) depending on if a 32-bit or 64-bit installation of Office was installed.  If you are willing to provide enough information to identify which version of Office was installed I am willing to submit an answer.

Comment: If the original OS was 8 or 10, it could have been upgraded to Windows 10, invalidating the sticker.

Comment: Also, stickers rub off over time, particularly on laptops.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - The question does not mention that fact.

Comment: Correct... the operative word was *if*.

Comment: If w7 go to C:\Windows\System32\License.rtf

version will be in the rich text file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the ../Windows/System32 folder for a file called "ntoskrnl.exe". If this file exists, it is at least an NT based system. (I assume you are not looking for Win95 or earlier.)

Now do a properties and examine the details for a product version.

4.x: NT 4.x
5.0: Windows 2000
5.1: Windows XP
5.2: Windows 2003 Server or Windows XP-64-bit
6.0: Windows Vista
6.1: Windows 7
6.2; Windows 8
6.3: Windows 8.1
10.0:Windows 10

This does not however  tell you which flavor of those systems (Pro, Home, etc).

On one device, I see 6.2.9200 so I can assume this is a Windows 8 disk.

Comment: If gpedit.msc is missing in system 32 folder it is home.

Answer (score 3):

If you can access the `C:\Windows` folder of the old HDD, you can use [Regedit, even from Windows PE, to access the Registry offline.](https://4sysops.com/archives/regedit-as-offline-registry-editor/) The Windows version information is in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` and also in values `CurrentBuild` and `Current MajorVersionNumber`** . [`CurrentVersion`](https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/cppmfc/get-windows-version-from-registry.html) is a string for a f.p. number. Likely data on a consumer PC:

- "5.1" = XP 32 bit
- "5.2" = XP 64 bit
- "6.0" = Vista
- "6.1" = Windows 7
- "6.2" = Windows 8
- "6.3" = Windows 8.1 **or later**
- "10.0" was used for Windows 10 *Preview*

Since Windows 10, [`CurrentBuild` and `Current MajorVersionNumber`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072543/reliable-way-to-get-windows-version-from-registry?newreg=5e42b2b10c224f7a8cc3276709954296) have the actual data, with `CurrentVersion` apparently frozen at "6.3" for backwards software compatibility.

[image: Using Regedit offline]

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, type `Regedit` in the *Search* box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Click on the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (HKLM) hive.
- Click on the *File* menu item `Load hive`.
- Open the file on the old HDD in `%windir%\system32\config\SOFTWARE`, where `%windir%` is likely `C:\Windows\`.
- Provide a name for this hive.
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SOFTWARE = %windir%\system32\config\SOFTWARE` in the offline hive.

[image: Finding Windows Version in Registry]

The data should provide all the information needed to install that Windows version.