# Is there a way to tell what kind of operating system current system has?

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, operating-systems

My question is as follows:
Is there a way for a linux installation disk (ubuntu 18.xx LTS on bootable stick) to know what operating systems computer has on a disk ?

I've found similiar topics here:
[How do I tell what version and edition of Windows is on the filesystem?](https://superuser.com/questions/363018/how-do-i-tell-what-version-and-edition-of-windows-is-on-the-filesystem/939344)

Which give adequate answer regarding Windows side. 
But what if USB is booted from Macbook or some other LaptopPC that has Linux?

Is there some sort of script or open-source application that (if executed) could detect all operating systems located on system ?

Comment: If it was a Mac, you probably couldn't even read the disk, HFS or APFS. If it was T2/boot mode/filevault protected, you wouldn't get permission even if you could read it.

Comment: " could detect all operating systems located on system ?" Not that I have ever seen, maybe someone could write one though,

Answer (score -1):

All Unixy systems should have a file `/etc/*-release` (perhaps several!)
or similar, containing the name and version of the operating system. Sure, a mischievous sysadmin can very well fake that, but it should be rather reliable. That presupposes that you can mount and read the relevant filessytem.

Comment: For Linux, the standard location is `/etc/os-release` or `/usr/lib/os-release`. But for non-Linux systems (BSDs, Solaris) I'm not sure if such a convention ever existed -- nor whether it needs to, as the kernel info from `uname` usually provides the information already...

Comment: @user1686, I remember such a file on Solaris and Ultrix, and perhaps on an IBM RT running AIX (sorry, machines long buried and forgotten, memory perhaps shot...).