# How to determine a Windows 7 license type from files under C:\?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, license, license-key

I need to create a repair disc for a machine running Windows 7 Professional x86, but first I need to find out the exact license type before burning the only DVD I have, because (believe me) **all** USB ports are malfunctioning and therefore cannot copy the ISOs to a thumb stick. The repair disc I have from another machine displays the following:

> This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the version of Windows

I only have a copy of the files under C:\ made by a colleague with Parted Magic so running `slmgr -dli` on cmd won't do it because I cannot boot the machine. Ideally, there should be a file somewhere indicating wether this copy has a retail, OEM or volume license. I did some digging and this [slmgr.vbs](https://pastebin.com/zLCHbcht) script seems to contain some variables present in the [dialog box](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/78664d1485966750-determine-if-windows-license-type-oem-retail-volume-retail_activation.png) from `slmgr -dli`, but it didn't take me anywhere...

I know this is possible on Windows XP by [reading the *setupp.ini* file](http://www.thetechguide.com/howto/setuppini.html), but is it on 7?

Comment: Can't also copy `slmgr.vbs` there?

Comment: It already is on the hard drive, I just pasted its contents.
On line 239 you can see the beginning of the second line from the dialog box, and on line 1184 it appears again along with this `strDescription` variable, but I could not find out the contents of this other variable...

Comment: See my answer here>>>>>>https://superuser.com/a/939344/40928

Comment: @Moab thanks for the info, but I already know what version is installed (W7 Pro, 32b). What I really need is to find out wether it's a retail, OEM or volume license.
But maybe, if there aren't any files referring to the license type, W7 doesn't see any difference between them. I am testing some installer images over USB before burning a DVD.

Comment: @ablon if gpedit.msc is present in system32 folder it is pro, if not it is home.

Comment: @moab. Not true. I run home and installed gpedit myself. See [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i/1018146#1018146) self ansered question by me :)

Comment: How many people do that......geeze.

Comment: UPDATE: I forgot to mention I could not test the disk images I had on USB because all the ports were somehow broken. But I managed to fix one by resoldering it and managed to repair the OS. I will leave this question as unanswered. Thanks everyone for the help!