# How can I check Windows 10 version without password?

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords, version

I got a laptop with Windows 10 for SSD and RAM upgrade.
The Windows 10 is original, but the account locked with password.

I want to know the version the Windows 10 (home, pro) for automatical activation after (re)install Windows. But without password I can not check it.

Sometimes the installer not need the version, but in this case I must to select.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why can't you just enable the built-in Administrator and run `winver`?

Comment: The owner does not know that.
And I can not access the admin account.

Comment: @coder1234 - You certainly can enable the built-in Administrator account, which is disabled by default, outside of that the COA sticker required by Microsoft should tell you which edition of Widows is installed.

Comment: PowerShell command: `Get-ComputerInfo -Property "WindowsEditionId"`

Comment: Thank you, but if I can not access the account, than how can I run this command? :)

Comment: You can run it with a normal unprivilaged user account.  If you have zero access then you enable the built-in Administrator account.  Windows 10 will automatically activate.  Knowing which edition you have installed currently isn't necessary to reinstall it.

Comment: There are the solution. :)

With the installer I can run the cmd.
And there I can check the version. :)

https://superuser.com/questions/363018/how-do-i-tell-what-version-and-edition-of-windows-is-on-the-filesystem